# Google Scholar - how to make English profile name show same citations as Cyrillic alphabet search results?

Tags: language, personal-name, google-scholar

I am helping an academic client from Russia with his publications in English language and have created a profile for him in Google Scholar. He already has pages and pages of citations when you look for his name in Russian. I would like the citations to be the same for searches in both Russian (Cyrillic) and English spelling of his name.

I've created Google Profile in English and manually added some of his Russian articles there, two weeks later nothing changed. He now has existing profile on Google Scholar - Oleg Matveychev, but the results for English spelling name are the same as a month ago, no matter what I do. Russian spelling results change all the time, as he is cited often. Any advice?

Comment: I am really happy to be earning all these points :D, but anybody has any idea what to do? My only option left now is to make sure his English name and English language excerpts are inserted in all future articles and possibly some already existing online documents that we have control over - such as some at his university and some on his personal website.

Comment: Many scholarly databases have a "merge profiles" function, mostly useful for people who published using different names (or different spellings of the same name). As far as I know Google Scholar doesn't, but it would be a good idea to add one (in my view, at least). Have you tried contacting Google?

Comment: is this different from "add"ing the "article group" filed under the cyrillic spelling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just saw this question on Twitter by chance, and I think I can answer it. At the moment, Google Scholar search results are not affected by the fact the person you're searching has created a Google Scholar Citations account. The correct way to search for this Russian researcher on Google Scholar would be:

author:"[cyrillic spelling]" OR author:"[latin spelling]"

That way you would get both sets of citations.

Comment: Thank you. "At the moment, Google Scholar search results are not affected by the fact the person you're searching has created a Google Scholar Citations account. " - is there an official help page from Scholar about this? I thought that what you would have to do if you had, say, a married name or a different spelling and you wanted to merge the results for two names.